# Direct POST of data from database doesn't show

Tags: php

Im having a hard time to make my php webservices right where in my login.php I use `$_POST` for `$username` and `$password` to get the data from the android. When I test my php code it give me the response `{"error":true,"error_msg":"Wrong credentials!"}` . Which I believe I get that error because I dont insert data. But my problem is when I try to direct the correct data, it still give me the same response

```
Login.php

    <?php

    require_once 'Config.php';

    $response = array("error"=> FALSE);

    if(isset($_POST['USER_ID'])){




        $username = $_POST['USER_ID'];
        $password = $_POST['LASTNAME'];



        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_UserDetails WHERE USER_ID = ? AND LASTNAME = ?");
        $query->execute(array($username,$password));

        $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        Database::disconnect();
    }
        if (!(empty($row))){

            $response["error"]= FALSE;
            $response["user"]["ID"]=$row["USER_ID"];
            $response["user"]["LASTNAME"]=$row["FIRSTNAME"];
            echo json_encode($response);    

        }
        else{
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Wrong credentials!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }





    ?>
```

**WHEN I CHANGE:**

```
    $username = $_POST['USER_ID'];
    $password = $_POST['LASTNAME'];
```

**INTO**

```
//01071997 and JOSH is correct data from my database
        $username = $_POST['01071997'];
        $password = $_POST['JOSH'];
```

It still give me the response:

```
{"error":true,"error_msg":"Wrong credentials!"}
```

Where I am doing wrong in above?

Comment: Why would `LASTNAME` be a password? You might want to check that.

Comment: `$response["user"]["LASTNAME"]=$row["FIRSTNAME"];` = time to refactor..

Comment: @LawrenceCherone because my USER_ID is the employee ID and the password is there LASTNAME

Comment: @LawrenceCherone refactor?  how to handle this error?

Comment: Start by dumping out `$row` then if your sure it should not be empty check what's being POSTed up, check the values match in the database etc, normal sanity checking/debugging. Don't change the parameters like your doing that's just going to break it e.g: `$username = $_POST['01071997'];` as your need to post up ?01071997=01071997 then.

Comment: How could I test my php if it sreally works then?. I check db and it was correct. I appreciate your answer but can you enlight me more? to make this php right?

Comment: `$username = $_POST['01071997'];` is looking for a POST field called `01071997`, which doesn't exist. Use `$username = '01071997';` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. but when i change it still the response is the same  {"error":true,"error_msg":"Wrong credentials!"}